# GCMIntentService + sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app works correctly, but I'm facing the following error:

```
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625): Handler (android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler){416ad6b0} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler) {416ad6b0} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage    (Handler.java:383)
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.postEventFromNative(MediaPlayer.java:1898)
10-04 14:04:38.182: W/MessageQueue(8625):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-04 14:04:38.182: V/MediaPlayer(8625): back from callback
```

I already saw [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20915) and the proposed workaround, but it doesn't work for me.

Anybody has another solution?

Answer (score 4):

```
 // create a handler to post messages to the main thread
 Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

Try This Code Hope It helps

Comment: You should explain that the problem is that a listener is trying to be called on a thread that is already dead. IntentService creates a new thread when you call the onHandleIntent method, and then kills that thread as soon as that onHandleIntent method returns. When a listener is created inside onHandleIntent, the result may be returned after the thread was killed. So moving the actions into a handler will create a new thread that will stay alive for the result.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a `Handler` in your `GCMIntentService`, you could use a `BroadcastReceiver` as it is done in the GCM sample app and as suggested in this answer: [Update TextView from GCMIntentService in Methods onRegistered and onUnregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902820/update-textview-from-gcmintentservice-in-methods-onregistered-and-onunregistered).