# Update TextView from GCMIntentService in Methods onRegistered and onUnregistered

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to set the text of a TextView in my MainActivity with the onRegistered and onUnregistered methods in the GCMIntentService class I've implemented. I can't set it directly because it's in a different class. What would be the best way to handle this?

A little background. I"m using the TextView to update the status on whether the device is registered or not and to display messages to the user. The reason I want to set it in the GCMIntentService is because once those methods are deplyed the device has completed the tasks. Right now when the user hits the register button it switches the status to registered, but the device isn't fully registered yet. I don't want to cause confusion or errors because they think the device is registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the GCM sample app. The way to do this is:

In the GCMIntentService you extended from GCMBaseIntentService, in onRegistered/onUnregistered, you can send a broadcast message (in the example, it's DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION). You just need to put the registration state in the intent, say 'REGISTRATION_STATE'. In your MainActivity, you then need to register a BroadcastReceiver and look for this message, e.g.:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mTextView.setText("Registration state is: " + intent.getExtras().getString("REGISTRATION_STATE");
    }
};
```

Comment: The developer site for Android is sometimes a bit confusing. Do you have a link to the sample? I would greatly appreciate it! I'll do some more research on the BroadcastReceiver. Thank you!

Comment: If you already downloaded the GCM Library, the sample should already be in your PC. Goto your Android SDK folder, look for folder /extras/google/gcm_v1/ and there should be a samples folder in there.